# How to load inline source in index faster

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, phaser-framework

html file with webpack and pahser. All the game code and external libraries are compile inline to the index.html.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve the inline source but with faster page loading? Somehow load the page with a embedded image and then load external scripts?

The reason I need this is I am building a playable ad for unity but their QA keeps failing my advertisement due to slow loading. They have not provided any sort of requirements on a specific loading time needed so I need to guess at this.

Currently my index page is exported with the inline source of the javascript in 1  code block. Ive noticed some other advertisers games have all their code split into multiple  tags would this allow for faster loading?

Ive attempted to use chunks but all this does is split up the code but keeps it all in one script block.

```
module.exports = env => {
    return {
        entry: {
            index: entryString.replace('{entryClass}', env.platform).replace('{game}', env.game ? env.game : ''),
            another: env.production ? spinePluginProd : spinePlugin,
            another: env.production ? phaserProd : phaser,
        },
        watch: env.watch == 'true',
        optimization: {
            minimizer: env.production ? [terserPlugin] : [],
        },
        output: {
            pathinfo: true,
            path: path.resolve(localDirectory, 'dist'),
            publicPath: './',
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        },
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
            },
        },
        plugins: getPlugins(env.platform, env.watch),
        module: {
            rules: getLoaders(env.platform, env.game),
        },
        node: {
            fs: 'empty',
            net: 'empty',
            tls: 'empty'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            alias: {
                'phaser': env.production ? phaserProd : phaser,
                'spinePlugin': env.production ? spinePluginProd : spinePlugin,
                // 'spine': spine
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows of way to load this any quicker the help would be appreciated. As a side not it seems Unity Ads only complains about our loading speed on apps over 2mb. The ads that are under 2mb seem to load fast enough which is why I'm assuming its just the page load and not the Phaser initialization

Comment: Check the size of the images you are loading, make sure that the libraries you are importing are not full of useless function you don't need.

Comment: The only 2 external libraries we use are phaser and spine.Im just looking at some way to improve the loading speed if possible with the current set of assets withotu compressign them crazily. Ive checked competitor ads and they seem to be fine with a 4mb index file. Only difference I see between theirs and ours is their inline scripts are split up

Comment: Are you loading asynchronous resources ? calling any API ?

Comment: No I am not using asynchronous to load the resources other than phaser loading which should be asynchronous? No, no api, we are not allowed external resources or any http calls in the package. All code used has to be embedded in the html file

Comment: Then i have no idea, sorry,

Answer (score 2):

The answer might come down to how they define 'slow loading.' You're not going to get that file to load any faster by splitting up the source into multiple script tags, it's the same amount of bytes (actually a few extra if you have multiple `<script>` tags).

But how are they measuring 'slow loading'? If they're just seeing how long it takes to load the file over the network then yes, you're going to have to look at ways to make that file smaller: make sure you're uglifying/tree shaking effectively to minimize your code as much as possible, apply that to library code also if necessary (and possible), and definitely compress your images with dedicated image compression tools (this is probably the low-hanging fruit in terms of file size; images are big).

If they're measuring how long it takes for the document's 'load' event to fire, on the other hand, you may be able to tweak things. By default the browser is going to load all of your code in order, and block on script tags, so the page won't load until all of your script tags have been interpreted. If you can put the bulk of your code execution into an event handler that fires on page load, however, the browser will see that you've defined an event handler for the load event, and keep right on trucking with loading the page, fire the load event, and then execute your code. That might be enough to get the fast metric you need.

Comment: awesome thanks I will give that a try, Yeah the assets are already pretty compressed so we wont gain anything from that end without losing to much quality, I will give using the load event a try thanks